# How to run multiple hbase (CDH Distro) instances on localhost

Tags: hbase, cloudera

Trying to figure out which properties I need to override in order to run two isolated HBase instances locally.

I've modified my hbase-site.xml to include:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2222</value>
  <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
  The port at which the clients will connect.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/zookeeper-old</value>
  <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
  The directory where the snapshot is stored.
  </description>
</property>
```

I've also specified `HBASE_PID_DIR`

However, when I start both CDH3 and CDH4.1, the shell on cdh3 just hangs when I execute a `list` command.

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run 2 separate HBase together like this. What will happen when both of them will try to access the same HDFS, use the same port, which RS will contact which HMaster etc? You should have different sets of config files if you really want to do that. Actually it doesn't make sense to run multiple distros on a single box. BTW, can I ask why do you need such a setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this is two real instances, but I had problems running a local HBase and a HBaseTestingUtility, so I would suggest these minimal overrides :

- Override master port (*hbase.master.port*) default is 60000
- Override regionserver port (*hbase.regionserver.port*) default is 60020
- Override HTTPServer ports for master and regionserver (hbase.master.info.port and hbase.regionserver.info.port). I recommend disabling these servers if you do not need the info UIs. This is done by setting their port to -1.